# How to make two same spritekit nodes to ignore collisions

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I want two nodes of the same object type to ignore each other without colliding. According to apple documentation,

"This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by performing a logical AND operation. If the result is a non-zero value, then this body is affected by the collision."

So, I set

```
ball.physics.categoryBitMask = 0x00000000;
ball.physics.collisionBitMask = 0x00000000;
```

This will make logical AND operation result in zero but they are still colliding each other for some reason.

How do you make it pass through each other?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the ball to collide with itself.  Set:

```
static const uint32_t ballCategory        =  0x1 << 1;
```

Change your bitmasks:

```
ball.physics.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
ball.physics.collisionBitMask = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the category mask to 0 .

Comment: There may be something wrong with ur category mask declaration . Try setting static const uint32_t ballCategory = 0x1 << 1; just before  @implementation UrClass:  and then set the categorybitmask to ballCategory